# probability splitting a line into segments with length $\geq$ 0.25

Tags: probability

We have a line with length 1 and we pick at random 2 points from it. What is the probability that each segment of the 3 is with length $\ge0.25$

What I have tried- Picking 2 points can be done in $100\times100$ ways. In order to pick the first point to be $\ge0.25$ we have $75$ ways. In order to pick the second point such that each of the segments is at least $0.25$ can be done in 50 ways since all of the possible are $75.$ So the answer should be $\frac{25 \times 50}{100 \times 100 }$

Comment: I would add that picking the first point should be greater than $0.25$ as you said but also less than $0.75$ because if it is more than $0.75$ than the line segment from the point to the end will be less than $0.25$

Comment: Assume that each point $U_1, U_2$ is picked uniformly on the line. $(U_1, U_2 \sim U[0,1])$

By symmetry this is equal to:
$2 P[U_1 \geq 0.25, U_2 > U_1, 0.5 \leq  U_2, U_2 \leq 0.75] = 2\int_{0.5}^{0.75}\int_{0.25}^{u_2}1 du_1 du_2$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst why is the ordering of the integrals like that?

Comment: You could do it either way round

Comment: the first integral represents picking a point $u_{1}$ which can range from 0.25 to $u_{2}$ once this is picked for the second point we have range from 0.5 to 0.75 and we multiply by 2 since it can be $u_{1}$ or $u_{2}$ chosen first?Is there a general formula for these kind of problems or a name when this method is applied or similar?

Comment: Yes this is correct. Not sure sorry